# CMakeLists.txt setup for Google Test

Tags: cmake, googletest

I have created a Gtest script that includes multiple `.h` files and tests the functions inside `.c` files. The test script works fine in VS2017, however, I need to build this using CMake in Ubuntu. I have created the following folder structure for my files, which has a `CMakeLists.txt` on the top level, and two folders of source and test as follows:

```
 CMakeLists.txt
├── source
│   ├── firstfile.c
│   ├── firstfile.h
│   ├── ...
│   ├── lastfile.c
│   ├── lastfile.h
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── test
│   ├── Test.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
```

The `Test.cpp` file calls the headers in the source folder and uses Gtest to test the functions defined in the `.c` files. Being unfamiliar with `CMake`, can you please guide me on what should I include in the three `CMakeLists.txt` files? I appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried to google? E.g. for [cmake googletest example](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+googletest+example). Numerous examples, including the ones on the Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not sure if you have one and a half hours in your life to watch the [great talk](https://youtu.be/bsXLMQ6WgIk) by Daniel Pfeifer, but if you do, I think that talk already covers what you need. Moreover, because you are new at SO, you might also consider reading on [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have, there are few that cover basic gtest. But what adds complexity to this is that a .cpp gtest file is calling extern "c" .h files and any thing I am doing doesn't seem to make the gtest read these .h and .c files.

Comment: Sagol @Arda izlerim!

Comment: "a .cpp gtest file is calling extern "c" .h files and any thing I am doing doesn't seem to make the gtest read these .h and .c files." - Well, this is what Stack Overflow is intended for: solving **specific** problems. Show **what have you tried**, and **what error you got**. Then we could be able to help you in your problem.